# replacing comma with numbers in a string

Tags: sed

I have text file contain strings like this

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,wxyz
```

I want to make it like this

```
1.abc
2.def
3.ghi
4.jkl
5.mno
6.pqr
7.stu
8.wxyz
```

how can i do that using sed?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222218/to-add-line-numbers-in-every-line-using-shell-command

Comment: You say "strings" (plural).  Can you give a larger example of the input file and what the output should look line? I'm assuming there could be multiple lines of these strings and that each should either be enumerated individually or as part of the overall sequence of entries.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this

```
echo abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,wxyz  | sed 's/,/\n/g' | nl -s "."

     1.abc
     2.def
     3.ghi
     4.jkl
     5.mno
     6.pqr
     7.stu
     8.wxyz
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=',|\n' '{printf "%s.%s\n",NR,$0}' <<< "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,wxyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of Perl approaches:

```
$ perl -F, -lne 'print ++$k.".$_" for @F' file
1.abc
2.def
3.ghi
4.jkl
5.mno
6.pqr
7.stu
8.wxyz

$ perl -pne 'chomp;s/([^,]+),*/++$k.".$1\n"/ge' file
1.abc
2.def
3.ghi
4.jkl
5.mno
6.pqr
7.stu
8.wxyz
```

And `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i"."$i}}' file
1.abc
2.def
3.ghi
4.jkl
5.mno
6.pqr
7.stu
8.wxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ <file sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed '=' | paste -d . - -

1.abc
2.def
3.ghi
4.jkl
5.mno
6.pqr
7.stu
8.wxyz
```